# Open hyperlinks from Remote Desktop locally?

Tags: .net, vb.net, rdp

I have a Winforms application written in VB.NET that we are migrating to a RemoteApp service. There are many dynamically generated hyperlinks in the program that when clicked will open in a browser in the RemoteApp session, instead of locally on the user's machine.

Is there way in VB.NET (or C#) to make the application aware of the remote session and somehow start a browser locally? Right now, we simply use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url)` to start up the browser.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your asking for is not part of RDP.  You can use things like [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to get it to work, maybe look into [Remote procedure call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) or you could create your own application that runs on the local computer all the time.  Using mapped local drives option, you could then write a file to the local HD and this custom program could read it and run the program locally.

I'm sure there more ways to do this but this is a good starting point.